# Problem with Linked Lists and Nodes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, linked-list

I am currently coding in Javascript, I am a newbie and I need help with my code. I want to create a Tree that contains Nodes(obviously) which points to a Linked List, this List will contain Node childs. The only node I need outside a Linked List is my root Node.

Anyways, my problem is with adding a Node to the Linked List of my Father node. 
Example:

Root -> LinkedList(Node->Node->Node->null) each points to another Linked List.

When I try to add a Node in the Linked List my first node is overwritten.

Code:

```
var list = new LinkedList();
var rootnode = new Node("Root");
list.add(rootnode, 20);
list.add(rootnode, "Como");
list.add(rootnode, "Estas");
list.add(rootnode, "ggg");
list.print(rootnode);

function LinkedList() {
  this.first = null;
  this.add = LinkedListAdd;
  this.print = LinkedListPrint;
  this.search = LinkedListSearch;
}

function Node(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.next = null;
  this.child = new LinkedList();
}

function LinkedListAdd(node, item) {
  if (!node.child.first) {
    node.child.first = new Node(item);
  } else {
    while (node.child.first.next) {
      node.child.first = node.child.first.next;
    }
    node.child.first.next = new Node(item);
  }
}
```

printing my `rootnode.child.first` gives me: `"Estas"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not override `node.child.first`, instead take a local variable:

```
    let acc = node.child.first;
    while(acc.next) acc = acc.next;
    acc.next = new Node(item);
```

---

Tip: You can access the LinkedList inside `LinkedListAdd` with `this`, which allows you to make this possible:

```
 root.children.add(10);
```

then you don't need this unnecessary `list`.